# Let $ A \in M_n(\mathbb{R}) $ be a matrix which satisfies $ A^2 + A + 5I_n = 0 $. Find the characteristic polynomial $ p_A $

Tags: linear-algebra, characteristic-polynomial

**Problem**: Let $ A \in M_n(\mathbb{R}) $ be a matrix which satisfies $ A^2 + A + 5I_n = 0 $. Find the characteristic polynomial $ p_A $

I don't really know how to find $ p_A $.We can write $ p_A = x^n + a_{n-1}x^{n-1} + a_{n-2}x^{n-2} + \cdots a_1 x + a_0 $. I know that by the Cayley-Hamilton theorem $ A $ is a root of $ p_A $. Also the polynomial $ f(x) = x^2 + x +5 $ satisfies $ f(A) = 0 $. I don't know how to proceed, I know $ p_A $ can be written as $ p_A(x) = f(x) \cdot g(x) $ where $ g(x) $ is some polynomial s.t. $ \deg g \leq n-2 $, but what next?

Thanks in advance for help!

Comment: What are the complex eigenvalues of $A$?

Comment: What leads you to believe there is a unique choice here?  Do you have any additional information about $A$?  As it stands there are multiple different choices of $A$ and $p_A$ satisfying the stated conditions.

Comment: @JMoravitz I don't think there are multiple choices.

Comment: $ f(x) =  ( x - \frac{-1+i \sqrt(19)}{2} )( x - \frac{-1-i \sqrt(19)}{2} )   $ , but $ A $ is a real matrix ( so its characteristic polynomial must be with real coefficients ) and  its eigenvalues are complex, what further Information can these give me?. And I don't have any further information besides what is stated in the problem

Comment: Every root of $p_A$ is an eigenvalue, and $p_A$ is a real polynomial. The only solution is that it is a power of $x^2 + x + 5$

Comment: So $x^2 + x + 5$ will be the minimal polynomial? In that case, the characteristic polynomial can be $ (x^2 + x + 5)^r \cdot g(x) $ where $ r  $ needs to be found and also $ g(x) $ ( $ g(x) \neq 0 $  for every x ) , the question is how can I find these?

Comment: @hazelnut_116 Every root of the characteristic polynomial is a root of the minimal polynomial. This is true over $\mathbb{C}$ as well so that your $g=1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only possible complex eigenvalues of $A$ are $\lambda = \frac{-1 - i\sqrt{19}}{2}$ and $\overline\lambda$. It follows that
\begin{equation}
\det(x I_n - A) = p_A(x) = (x-\lambda)^\alpha (x - \overline\lambda)^{n-\alpha}
\end{equation}
As $p_A$ is real, it follows that $\alpha = n -\alpha$, hence $n$ is even and finally
\begin{equation}
p_A(x) = (x^2 + x + 5)^{n/2}
\end{equation}

Comment: Why are $\lambda$ and $\bar{\lambda}$ the only possible complex eigenvalues?

Comment: @DatBoi because if $AX = x X$ then $0 = (A^2  + A + 5 I)X = (x^2 + x + 5)X$, hence $x^2 + x + 5 = 0$

Comment: Right, but why are they the **only** complex eigenvalues?

Comment: If the multiplicity of $ (x-\lambda)^\alpha $ is $ \alpha $, then why the multiplicity of $ ( x - \overline\lambda)^{n-\alpha}$ is $ n - \alpha $?

Comment: @hazelnut_116 The degree of $p_A$ is always $n$.